# jQuery Bootstrap Date Picker Selected Date Wrong with Fixed Date Value Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date

I have a jQuery Bootstrap Date Picker. It works normally and OK on the input form.

Now face a problem when I want to edit the date, it's not show selected date based on previous choose date.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="dateFromDatabase" id"dateFromDatabase" value="20-Aug-2017"/>
```

Example Date:

```
20-Aug-2017
```

When I click that input box, date picker will show but the selected date is not working based on that value.

*I need to type something on the keyboard and then the date selected will be correct. (I think on Change function?)

My Question, how can I set it automatically date based on input value on click?

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());

$('#dateFromDatabase').datepicker(
{
    format: "dd-M-yyyy",
    calendarWeeks: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: date
});
```

Comment: You have startDate that is greater than input value

Comment: Sorry type wrong date, 20-Aug-2017

Comment: I don't see any error then.. it should work fine.

Comment: Yes you correct, but I need to type something on keyboard then I can see the date changed correctly based on input text

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/1116/ do you have any other library for datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

`format` is not valid option change it to `dateFormat`

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());

$('#dateFromDatabase').datepicker(
{
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    calendarWeeks: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: date,
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
<input type="text" name="dateFromDatabase" id="dateFromDatabase" value="20-Jul-2017"/>
```